# Where in Egypt did the Jews live while they were still slaves in Egypt

Tags: am-yisrael-jewish-nation, egypt

Where in Egypt did the Jews live while they were still slaves in Egypt?

> So the Egyptians made the Israelites their slaves. They appointed
>   brutal slave drivers over them, hoping to wear them down with crushing
>   labor. They forced them to build the cities of Pithom and Rameses as
>   supply centers for the king.- Exodus 1:11

Comment: What makes you think they moved from where they lived before they were slaves?

Comment: Isn't it clear it was A separate residential area in (the region of) Goshen? What exactly is your question: where this was?

Comment: I think the question is very clear. No need for all these comments.

Comment: @moshe I don't think the question is very clear at all. Does he know they had lived in Goshen and is wondering based on something if that still was true? Is he trying to understand where Goshen was? We don't know because he doesn't explain what he's thinking. That's why these comments are helpful since they help him realize what info he should have included in the question. Your answer below may or may not be helpful to him. Which means you may have wasted your time.

Comment: I've wondered how they could easily borrow stuff from their neighbors on that last night if they were off by themselves in Goshen.  Is that (part of) why you're asking?

Comment: @I've always considered Goshen to be a suburb in which the Israelites dominated the population primarily but there were plenty of goyim too. Like those places in NY.

Answer (score 3):

Rashi (Shmot 19:4, quoted below) writes that when the Jews left Egypt, God quickly gathered the Jews scattered throughout the Land of Goshen and brought them to Raamses in order to leave together. We see according to this that many Jews lived throughout the Land of Goshen. Furthermore, since Rashi is referring to a miraculous event, of how numerous Jews that were scattered throughout the land quickly gathered to Ramses, if there were other places where they lived Rashi would have included that in his commentary. Therefore it would be safe to assume that most, if not all, Jews lived in Goshen.

> ואשא אתכם - זה יום שבאו ישראל לרעמסס, שהיו ישראל מפוזרין בכל ארץ גושן, ולשעה קלה כשבאו ליסע ולצאת נקבצו כלם לרעמסס

Comment: and where is "Goshen"?

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't know where Goshen is.

Comment: What about all the Jews who lived in Raamses (possibly because they worked there) who didn't need to be flown anywhere? Your argument is fallacious (as in your conclusion doesn't follow from the premises). What would be safe to assume is that most, if not all, Jews lived in Goshen or Raamses (or small towns near Raamses).

Comment: See Bereshit 47:11 and commentaries there that this Ramses was in Goshen, this is the same Ramses that is mentioned in Shmot 19:4, see commentaries there. Ramses where they worked was somewhere else - see commentaries on Shmot 1:11.

Comment: You're finally coming close to putting together a sourced logical answer :) Distinguishing Raamses and Rameses is indeed a good move. Remember to edit your post to include all relevant details